# Is this proof good? Identifying extreme points of the unit ball in a function space

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I want to prove: If $K$ is compact $T_2$ then the extreme points of the unit ball of $C(K)$ are precisely the functions $f\in C(K)$ such that $|f(k)|=1$ for all $k\in K$. Here is my proof: Can someone say of this this right or where you see mistakes in the argumentation?

---

$\impliedby$: We first want to show that all $f\in C(K)$ with $\left|f(k)\right|=1$ for all $k\in K$ are extreme points. Thus suppose we have functions $f,g:K\rightarrow\left[-1,1\right]$ and $\alpha\in\left(0,1\right)$ such that $1=\alpha f(k)+(1-\alpha)g(k)$ for all $k\in K$ then we must have $1=\left|f\right|=\left|g\right|$.

$\implies$: Let $f$ be an extreme point of the unit ball $B$. Then we must have $\left\|f\right\|_{\infty}=1$, thus there exists $x_0\in K$ such that $\left|f(x_0)\right|=1$. Suppose $\left|f(x_0)\right|=1$, then we want to prove that $\left|f(k)\right|=1$ for all $k\in K$. To sake a contradiction suppose we can find $k_0\in int(K)$ such that $0<\left|f(k_0)\right|<1$ and define $\epsilon>0$ to be $\epsilon=1-\left|f(k_0)\right|>0$. Now notice that $f$ in continuous thus we may find a $\delta>0$ such that $B(x_0,\delta)\subseteq int(K)$ and $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<f(x)<1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ since $x\in B(x_0,\delta)$. Now we can apply the Urysohn's Lemma to conclude that there exists a function $h:K\rightarrow\left[-1,1\right]$ such that $h(k_0)=1$ and $h(x)=0$ if $x\notin B(x_0,\delta)$. Now we can get two new functions $f_1=f+\frac{\epsilon}{2}h$ and $f_2=f-\frac{\epsilon}{2}h$ in the unit ball. Notice that $f=\frac{1}{2}(f_1+f_2)$ therefore $f$ can not be an extreme point. Thus $\left|f(k)\right|=1$ for all $k\in K$.

---

Thank you for remarks.

Comment: Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The proof of the first implication looks incorrect to me. We want to show that if $|f(k)| = 1$ for all $k \in K$ then $f$ is extreme. So suppose that we can write $f(k) = \alpha g(k) + (1-\alpha) h(k)$ where $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. This is only possible when $f(k) = g(k) = h(k)$. This means that $g$ and $h$ must be the same function and thus $f$ is indeed extreme. You only proved that $|g| = |h|$ and this doesn't exclude the possibility that $g$ and $h$ be different functions and thus $f$ not extreme. Also note that your proof is confusing because in the first sentence your $f$ is something else than in the second sentence. Choosing names carefully is very important so that you don't confuse others and yourself.

The second implication looks basically correct to me. But note that your proof only works if it's possible to use Urysohn's lemma, i.e. if the unit ball in $C(X)$ is normal. Can you prove that this is the case?